# Why doesn't Magento Dhl-intraship create intraship shipments or documents?

Tags: magento, dhl

For some reason, the dhl intraship plugin does not seem to recognize when there are new orders. The cronjobs are running fine, but from what I could see in the code, they are always starting with intraship/shipment entities, but the corresponding table in my DB is empty, therefore the cronjobs do nothing.

How do I get the plugin to fill the table? Hopefully I could go from there and fix possible config problems.

My Magento Version is CE 1.7.0.2

I have no local overrides and no modifications in community/Dhl folder (I reinstalled and there were no changes in git)

Thanks! And sorry for the vague question, but I have no error messages whatsoever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appeared another module was listening to the `sales_order_invoice_save_after` event, creating a shipment and increasing the `QtyShipped` for orders right when the Invoice came in. Therefore the orders `canShip()` returned `false` when the intraship module ran the cronjob.